# React, Redux: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ...)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fetching data (an object) into a redux state and put this object into a react prop.

The code is working fine if the data is retrieved on a button click. But I would like to retrieve the data when the component is rendered which does not work. Instead, I get the error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')*

This code does work and I can see the retrieved object in the redux-state (in Chrome redux-devtool):

```
export class Main extends Component {

 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getQuery();
 }

 onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props.query.query.id)
 } 

 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.onClick}>Print id</Button>
        </div>
    )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 query: state.query.query
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getQuery })(Main)
```

But this code does not work:

```
export class Main extends Component {

 componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getQuery();
    console.log(this.props.query.query.id) //This line throws an error
 }

 onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props.query.query.id)
 } 

 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={this.onClick}>Print id</Button>
            <p>this.props.query.query.id</p> //This line throws an error
        </div>
    )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 query: state.query.query
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getQuery })(Main)
```

I am new to react and redux, so any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the query add the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like so: `this.props.query?.id`
and in `mapStateToProps` you are putting `state.query.query` thus inside the JSX you can access to the `id` directly: `this.props.query?.id` otherwise it will throw an error like you've mentioned.

And when you need to use any variable inside the JSX you should put it inside a curly braces for example:
 `<li>{this.props.query?.id}</li>`

Answer (score -1):

you can use chaining operator like this

```
<p>this.props.query?.query?.id</p> //This line throws an error
```

or first verify then print

```
{ this.props.query && this.props.query.query &&
<p>this.props.query.query.id</p> 
}
```